# Use vars or repeat in /regex/.test

Tags: regex

How to use variables or repeat through string in regular expressions?

```
/^(var1)bar(var1)$/.test('foobarfoo') //true
```

Comment: I think you are looking for *capture groups* and *backreferences*. Search about that.

Comment: Yea, \1 works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this:

So if you wanted to replace "foobarbaz" into "bazbarfoo", you'd do this in sed like this (not sure what language you are using):

```
s/^(foo)(bar)(baz)$/\3\2\1/
```

You first capture your desired output with brackets () and then you can use the matches with backreferences like \1 \2 \3.

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you want?

```js
console.log(/^([a-z]+)bar\1$/.test('foobarfoo'));
```